# How do you smoke water?

Tags: smoking, water

Roux mention in [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/additional-ingredients-to-homemade-pasta/7805#7805) smoking water. How do you do this? What does it taste like? How do you use it?

Sounds fascinating!

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1sAkZF7SCQ

Comment: The link you posted is broken, what was the question you're referring to?

Comment: The link Seth refers to is to a now-deleted question asking for a list of suggestions for adding to pasta.  The entire answer read *"If you have access to a smoker, smoke water and use that for making your dough."*, and was written by the same person as the accepted answer here

Comment: With a [water pipe](https://dankstop.com/blogs/blog/how-to-choose-the-best-water-pipe)?

Comment: This is a dupe of Could you smoke a sauce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fill a basin or hotel pan with water.

Place in your smoker. Ensure the smoker heat is set below 100C/212F (adjust as necessary for distance above/below sea level).

Um... smoke. An hour should do fine. More if you want more. Optionally strain through a superbag or muslin to remove any deposited particulate matter.

Comment: What do you use it for?

Comment: I haven't yet, but the bright minds at studiokitchen.com use it for making pasta.

Comment: Why not use liquid smoke?  It is produced almost the same way but some of the [tar removed through filtration.](http://www.google.com/patents?vid=USPAT5637339)

Comment: I don't know what it is, but I just find the flavour of liquid smoke not very pleasant. Too intense and difficult to titrate? Maybe. I don't know. But the times I have had to use it in cooking--even under the direction of a much more experienced chef--I have not enjoyed the flavour at all. Different strokes I suppose.